# Replicate Random Numbers from Visual Basic with Python

Tags: python, vba, random-seed

I have a code in Visual Basic that generates a vector of random numbers for a given seed (456 in my case). I need to replicate that code in Python and I am thinking if it is possible to generate with Python the same vector of random numbers, that is, to select the same seed as in VBA.

Let me show an example:

In VBA I have the following code:

```
Function rnd_seed(seed)
    Dim x(1 To 10) As Double
    Rnd (-1)
    Randomize seed
    For i = 1 To 10
        x(i) = Rnd
    Next i
    rnd_seed = x
End Function
```

With this function, I obtain the values (for seed 456):

```
0.014666617 
0.462389946 
0.098651111 
0.189074159 
0.107685387 
0.219710588 
0.967558324 
0.409745097 
0.213494837 
0.848815441
```

In Python, I use the following code (as suggested by K-D-G):

```
seed = 456

import random
random.seed(seed)
arr=[]
for i in range(10):
    arr.append(random.random())
```

With this Python code, I obtain the following values:

```
[0.7482025358782363,
 0.9665873085424435,
 0.4352093219057409,
 0.7942997804992433,
 0.6481497216250237,
 0.6174050474978059,
 0.8222710780743806,
 0.7895737180242367,
 0.8864808985728122,
 0.3264489135810307]
```

I see that the values obtained for VBA and Python are different. My question is if it is possible to generate with Python the same random numbers that I have generated with VBA. Is there any way to map the VBA and Python seeds?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot generate the exact same random numbers unless you know exactly how the VBA algorithm for random numbers is implemented. Why do you need the exact same numbers though?

Comment: I just wanted to know if it was possible, because I have a code that performs a series of calculations for which, at first, it generates random numbers, and I wanted to get exactly the same results after running all the code.

Comment: You'll get deterministic behavior with Python's random as well, just not the same numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
import random
random.seed(seed)
arr=[]
for i in range(n):
    arr.append(random.random())
```

Note random.random() returns value between 0 and 1 if you want integers over a range use random.randint(start, stop)

Comment: My question is if it is possible to generate with Python the same random numbers that I have in VBA. I have edited the question to give more detail.